# Linked list function that determines if values are in strictly ascending order

Tags: c, linked-list

I have written a function below that takes a pointer to the front of a linked list and determines if the values in that list are stored in strictly ascending order. If this is the case, the function should return 1; otherwise it should return 0.

```
 struct listnode {
    int data;
    struct listnode* next;
 };

 int ascendingOrder(struct listnode* front) {

 struct listnode* current = front; 

 if(current->data == NULL)
    return current->data; 

 while(current->next != NULL) {

     if(current->data < current->next->data)
         return 1; 
     }

     else
         return 0; 

     } 
 }
```

Would this work, and if not how come?

Comment: The snippet does not even compile. There's an `else` without a corresponding `if`.

Comment: Also check what happens to a list with 1 single node :)

Comment: I edited the code, but I'm not sure I made the right corrections

Comment: Also, please always indent your code.

Comment: Even after your edit, it still has a dangling `else`. Be consistent with your indentation levels to find these errors easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few things that don't look right. For starters, your version won't even compile. In addition, if the first item is less than the second item, your function returns. It doesn't even check the other items.

I'd do something more like this (untested).

```
int IsAscending(struct listnode* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return TRUE;

    while(node->next != NULL)
    {
        if (node->data > node->next->data)
            return FALSE;
        node = node->next;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: +1 ... but what about the "strictly" bit? The list `1 -> 2 -> 2 -> 3` is not strictly ascending.

Comment: @pmg: It wasn't entirely clear to me what the OP wanted here. Of course, if you want it how you've described you could just change the comparison from `>` to `>='.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work because you return after comparing the first two list items. You could put "continue;" (or just leave it blank) where your return 1 is, then put return 1 outside the while loop at the end of the program. That way it only returns 0 if it runs into a point where current > next and returns 1 if it gets through all items without that happening. Also your brackets are off, you have an extra one right after return 1. and you aren't ever changing the current node to the next node, you must set that at the bottom of the while loop.